# Debugging .NET assemblies built outside of Dev Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have a .NET project which references another assembly that is built outside of the solution.

I have all of the source code to the other assembly - but I can only add it as a ".DLL" reference rather than adding the actual project as a dependency.

The problem is that when I step into the external code, the debugger "steps over" it.

How do I enable "source code" debugging for the external .NET assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the dll and want to step into the binary, you would need the dll's pdb file. 
About debugging .Net source in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In VS2010 it is also possible to debug the raw .NET framework source code. To debug errors in the framework, check out the following site for more information:
[Visual Studio 2010: Debug .NET framework assemblies](http://www.lazerwire.com/2011/11/vs2010-debug-net-assemblies.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Tools / Options / Debugging / General, there's an option called "Enable Just my code (Managed Only)". Turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have the source code open in another visual studio, once you have started you application you can attach VS to that other process. 
Ten you can set a breakpoint in that source code and debug from there.